# Crypto exchange - what do BTCUSD SELL and LTCBTC SELL mean?

Tags: trading, terminology

I just downloaded an app that forecasts the crypto market. The app seems to be nice but I don't understand the forecast interface. What does this mean?

```
BTCUSD SELL,  
LTCBTC SELL
```

Does it mean that I can sell my bitcoin to someone that has dollars?

For the second, does it also mean that I can sell my LTC to someone that has BTC that is invariably buying BTC with LTC?

Answer (score 1):

```
BTCUSD          sell
  |               |
Trading Pair    Advice from the Platform
```

So **BTCUSD** is a trading pair
in trading you always exchange something (BTC) for something (USD)

the last part is the advice from the platform what you  could do with the specific pair. (in this case **sell** the first for the second)
this is my guess because we do not know the context really, some forcast software/apps are also integrated with the ability to exchange directly if you open an account with them)

As for my interpretation (assuming it is only forecast):

If you have BTC they advice you to sell BTC for USD because the market will be favourable this way (you will profit form this trade in the future because they expect the USD to be valued higher than BTC).

If you have LTC they advice you to sell LTC for BTC because the market will be favourable this way (you will profit form this trade in the future because they expect the BTC to be valued higher than LTC)

STRONG ADVICE
Do your own research about what could happen in the future, forecasts are forecasts and nothing more, don't come crying because you lost money by trusted a forecast. They may be factually based, but they can still be completely wrong. You may lose everything, many people have and will.

Answer (score 0):

BTCUSD means you are selling your BTC in exchange of USD, same with LTCBTC, you are selling your LTC in exchange of BTC. That both works with spot and leverage trading settings.